# lock/unlock text input on checkbox checked/unchecked

Tags: javascript

I've got `checkbox` and `text input`. What I need is to disable/enable the field by checking/unchecking corresponding checkbox.

I'm interested in plain javascript approach to this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The very basic method to achieve this is:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="yourBox">
<input type="text" id="yourText">
<script>
document.getElementById('yourBox').onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById('yourText').disabled = this.checked;
};
</script>
```

Every [`input[type=checkbox]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLInputElement#Properties) element has a property `checked`, which represents the state of the checkbox. Input elements can be disabled by setting `disabled` to true. Combining these two properties results in the desired behaviour.

Comment: Could that be applyed on two neighbor table cells?

Comment: @helicera: Most likely. All you have to do is get the right element reference, using DOM traversal methods.

Comment: The `change` event doesn't fire until the checkbox loses focus, so the `click` event (which I believe fires even when the checkbox is changed via keyboard or touch) may be better.